# Postgresql needs to run command every time for startup

Tags: postgresql

I'm on RHEL6 and have installed PostgreSQL. Now whenever I want to start development I need to run the following command to start PostgreSQL

/opt/PostgreSQL/9.5/bin/postgres -D /opt/PostgreSQL/9.5/data

Then it halts for that terminal and I need to start another session of postgresql into another terminal. Whats wrong in Installation? and How to rectify this problem?

[Image of practical for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysm3V.png)

Comment: Have you tried to start with [pg_ctl](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html) your DB instead? :)

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html

> The utility command pg_ctl can be used to start and shut down the
>   postgres server safely and comfortably.
>
> If at all possible, do not use SIGKILL to kill the main postgres
>   server. Doing so will prevent postgres from freeing the system
>   resources (e.g., shared memory and semaphores) that it holds before
>   terminating. This might cause problems for starting a fresh postgres
>   run.

use `pg_ctl -D /opt/PostgreSQL/9.5/data start` instead, otherwise one day your database will tell you about corrupted data

Comment: Yes, but I have to run it every time I logged into the operating system.

Comment: no you dont' `pg_ctl` starts potgres and exits, leaving postgres running. In case its not so - use `services postgresql start` or alike